# geography::Point' failed because parameter x is not allowed to be null. BEST PRACTICE

Tags: sql-server

trying to build a table like :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_example](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [lat] [float] NULL,
    [long] [float] NULL,
    [location]  AS ([geography]::Point([long],[lat],4326))
)
```

Problem, the statement said before, when one of the parameters is null, Point fails (instead of returning NULL), that a liitle strage

before building our onw function to test if no value is null, and then using point

**any best practice or idea ?**

I can find related questions, I wonder is anybody use POINT at all ...

Comment: Think about it, what's the point of having lat/lng coordinates if one of them is unknown? If one could be null, why not just leave out location entirely and just use the lat/long columns within the application?

Comment: You could make the calculated column conditional, I don't think that is useful though. I agree with @Reisclef in that it doesn't make sense to have one point without the other. I would make them both NOT NULL and validate the inputs.

Comment: @Reisclef, indeed thee is no sense of having one coordinate and not the other, I am agree, but the data is what it is ... and we have to deal with it . The thing goes with the function, giving an error instead of a null.

Comment: @JacobH, thanks, that was one of my first thought, but (not but to you), I though it couldn't be so easy and straightforward, and MS should have thought that into the function ...

Answer (score 3):

Make the calculated column conditional. That is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_example](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [lat] [float] NULL,
    [long] [float] NULL,
    [location]  AS CASE WHEN lat IS NOT NULL AND long IS NOT NULL THEN ([geography]::Point([long],[lat],4326)) ELSE NULL END
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[_example]
    ( [lat], [long] )
VALUES
    ( NULL, 0.0 ),
    ( 0.0, NULL ),
    ( 0.0, 0.0 )
```

As a side note, I would make that computed column persisted if you want to actually do anything with it (like use it as a predicate in a query).

Comment: Great, that will solve the case , for now, je je

what about an "overlap" function so it override the behaviour when one of the parameters is null ?? (so it can be used all allong in future cases)

Comment: I don't understand your follow up question. The implementation I have allows for either or both to be null. What is the desired behavior?